# Scala SBT Cannot Add Dependency (geotrellis)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, geotrellis

I'm new to Scala and working with IntelliJ Community Edition.

I open a new project and edit the build.sbt file to contain the following:

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.locationtech.geotrellis" %% "geotrellis-raster" % "1.0.0" % "1.1.0" ,
  "org.locationtech.geotrellis" % "geotrellis-shapefile_2.11" % "1.1.0"
).map(_
  .exclude("com.azavea.geotrellis", "geotrellis-proj4_2.11")
  .exclude("com.azavea.geotrellis", "geotrellis-raster_2.11")
)
```

After that, I refresh the project, and I get the following errors in the error file:

[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add dependency 'org.locationtech.geotrellis#geotrellis-raster_2.11;1.0.0' to configuration '1.1.0' of module default#test_2.11;1.0 because this configuration doesn't exist!

[error] (*:update) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add dependency 'org.locationtech.geotrellis#geotrellis-raster_2.11;1.0.0' to configuration '1.1.0' of module default#test_2.11;1.0 because this configuration doesn't exist!

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Main issue seems to be two different version numbers on one of your dependencies.

```
"org.locationtech.geotrellis" %% "geotrellis-raster" % "1.0.0" % "1.1.0"
```

Should be

```
"org.locationtech.geotrellis" %% "geotrellis-raster" % "1.0.0"
```

or

```
"org.locationtech.geotrellis" %% "geotrellis-raster" % "1.1.0"
```

if you want the 1.1.0 version